# RSS feed for new AppleTv titles?

Tags: appletv

Is there perhaps an RSS feed or some other method of being notified of new AppleTv titles as they become available?

Answer (score 2):

There should be, but almost all I found were people complaining that there wasn't one.

Given that, one or more of these might help:

- [Apple TV Junkie](http://www.appletvjunkie.com) has [a feed](http://www.appletvjunkie.com/feed/) of at least some new movies.
- Apple has an [iTunes RSS Generator](http://itunes.apple.com/rss)
  While it doesn't do new movies, it will give you top movies and top movie rentals.
- If you felt like getting into the code, here's [the  iTunes search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).
- [This URL](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewRoom?fcId=328581356&id=39) launches iTunes and goes directly to the "New Movies to Rent or Own" section of the iTunes store.